# C# Quando abrir a form 2 esperar 5 segundo e abrir a form 3

Tags: c#, winforms

Preciso que ao carregar a form 2 o programa esperasse 5 segundos de maneira a abrir automaticamente a form 3 como faço isso?

```
private void LetTheGameStart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}
```

este é o único código que tenho de momento

Comment: Porque não inclui um componente Timer e quando atingir o tempo, abrir o form? Estude o funcionamento do [Timer no MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Já consegui por a começar agora tenho de descobrir como por a acabar ao fim de 5 segundos

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o que procura? Da forma que esta, não esta claro o que deseja. Clique para [edit] a pergunta e adicione mais informações, e se possível o código que já possui. Dessa forma será mais fácil encontrar a solução que procura.

Comment: Não percebi uma coisa o que é o alarmCounter podes me ajudar?

Comment: Na verdade você precisa entender o funcionamento do Timer. O componente possui as propriedade Enabled, [Interval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx). Toda vez que está ativa, ele percorre um tempo até atingir Interval. 
[Exemplo SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13627032/2788478). Quando atingir o Interval, ele dispara o evento [OnTick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.timer.ontick(v=vs.110).aspx). Em interval, o tempo é em milisegundos.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/169892/display-a-form-for-a-period-of-time) que também possui bons exemplos.

Comment: private void HelloForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            label1.Text = "Hello " + Username;
            t.Interval = 5000;
            t.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimerTicked);
            t.Start();
        }
        public void OnTimerTicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            t.Stop();
            LetTheGameStart LTGS = new LetTheGameStart();
            LTGS.Show();
            this.Hide();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Particularmente, eu acho extremamente desnecessário utilizar um timer para este tipo de operação. Use um timer quando quiser repetir algo dentro de um determinado tempo, ou então para casos que precisem de um pouco mais de trabalho. Você pode usar `Task.Delay()` para fazer sua aplicação esperar determinado tempo sem travar a GUI.

```
private async void LetTheGameStart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);

    AbrirForm2(); // Coloque aqui o código para abrir o form2
}
```

Com `Task.Delay` se obtém o atraso desejado. O `await` faz com que isso não trave a aplicação.

---

#### Usando `Timer`

Se você quiser insistir no `Timer` (isso até pode ser melhor em versões antigas do .NET Framework) será necessário definir um `Interval` para este timer e um evento `Tick`. O **`Interval`** é o tempo (em milissegundos) em que este timer será disparado e o **`Tick`** é o evento que será executado. Veja um exemplo:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Timer timer = new Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Interval = 5000; //Definir o intervalo em 5 segundos
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick; // Inscrever o evento tick
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form().Show(); // Aqui deve-se abrir o Form2
        timer.Stop(); // Parar o timer, porque isso só é necessário uma vez
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Start(); // Iniciar o timer quando o form for carregado
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 pelo `async`/`await`, mas a solução com `Timer` pode vir a ser útil se o alvo do `.NET Framework` for igual ou inferior ao `.NET 4`

Comment: @TobyMosque Right on time =D